# How can I open a module with filtred data ??Invalid field

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

I added a module "Base Candidat" in this module base.candidat I want to open the applications of a specific canidate (that have the same email as the candidate )
I added this function to base_candidat.py

```
def action_get_applications(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    model, action_id = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'hr_recruitment', 'action_hr_job_applications')
    action = self.pool.get(model).read(cr, uid, action_id, context=context)
    email_ids = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context).email_candidat
    candidature_ids = self.pool.get('hr.applicant').search(cr, uid, [('email_from', '=', email_ids)], context=context)
    action['context'] = {'default_res_model': self._name, 'default_res_id': ids[0]}
    action['domain'] = str([('candidature_ids', 'in', email_ids)])
    return action
```

I have no result . 
Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

In odoo 8 you can try this code:

```python
@api.multi
def action_get_candidatures(self):
    action_id = self.env.ref('hr_recruitment.action_hr_job_applications')
    action = action_id.read()[0]
    action['context'] = {'default_res_model': self._name, 'default_res_id': self.ids[0]}
    action['domain'] = str(['&', ('res_model', '=', self._name), ('email_from', '=', 'candidat01@exemple.com')])
    return action
```

Comment: when I use my code without the action domain I got all the applications But I want to filter this applications based on email adress

Comment: I have tried your code but I got the same error : Invalid field 'res_model' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('res_model', '=', 'base.candidat') on hr_applicant (ctx: )>"